# Running old games without CD

Tags: games, classic-mac-os

I want to run Diablo (Windows/Mac game) on OS 9 but without using the CD. After installation, the user is required to insert the disc for the game to start. Making a .dmg image didn't work (as suggested by a website), as OS 9 doesn't recognise the format. Anyone knows something that might work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating a .img or .smi file.

To get from a dmg to an img try the following:

```
hdiutil convert /path/to/file.dmg -format RdWr -o /destination/of/file.img
```

Comment: Im getting this 
Usage: hdiutil convert -format <format> -o <outfile> [options] <image>

Comment: On OSX lion terminal

Comment: I can't find any terminal on OS9...

Comment: Do it in OSX and then transfer it over. Make sure the file does not contain any spaces in the name. That often will result in an error. You can rename the new .img after the fact.

Comment: Few more comments for you: When you are making the dmg in disk utility, make sure you do not give it a partition map, that will return an error and be sure after creating the dmg you unmount it (eject it). If you are still having issues, post the error that appears right about the 'Usage...' output

Comment: There was a space on the name of a folder on path to .dmg thats why I got the Usage error. Having created and mounted the .img i get an error saying I need to install the game cd when trying to run the game. If I try to run it from the .img I am getting an error saying I need at least 10 mb free space while the .img is writable.. Any thoughts ? Thanks for helping btw..

Comment: The error when trying to run it from the image makes sense. It thinks it is a CD and most game CD's are not writeable. By "install the game cd" do you mean insert the game cd? Is the name of the disk image (and file name) exactly what the name of the actual CD is? Thats the only thing I can think of. If I had OS9 I might be able to figure it out, but alas I haven't used that in years. Sorry mate.